# OTAs ( Booking Airbnb ) API Accesss

Tags: api, ota

Both OTAs say that they dont give access to their apis at the time

booking: At this point in time, we are not granting access to API.

airbnb: At this time, we are not accepting new access requests for our API. Our global team of partner managers will reach out to prospective partners based on the supply opportunity your business represents, strength of your technology, and ability to support our shared customers.

And has anyone worked with otagateway.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So :

- You don't post an question
- If you ask "why can't i have an API key" it's because they choose who have the right and who can be beneficial for them